# How to Print associative array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an associative array in php, how can i print it with php foreach loop

```
Array( [0] => Array ( [fb_user_id] => 100000058716604 [accept_status] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [fb_user_id] => 100004069844270 [accept_status] => 1 ) )
```

Tried this but no success, i want to print the fb_user_id

```
 foreach($resulttotal[fb_user_id] as $value)
 {
      echo $value;
 }
```

Please help me, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You doing incorrectly, It will be like:

```
foreach($resulttotal as $value)
{
   echo $value['fb_user_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to use a regular for loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($resulttotal); $i++) {
 $row = & $resulttotal[$i];
 echo $row['fb_user_id'];
}
```

But this could be a `foreach` too.

```
foreach($resulttoal as $key) {
  echo $key['fb_user_id']
}
```